# Lazy loaded route base url behaving strangely

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I have created an Application with a Component Library. My library contains routes. When I try to lazy load the library into the application I use the following route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'test2', loadChildren: () => import('my-lib' ).then(x => x.MyLibModule) },
];
```

I import that route into my AppRoutingModule for the application:

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

In the library module MyLibModule I define my library routes and import them using the forChild method

```
imports: [
   ...
   RouterModule.forChild(routerConfig),
   ...
 ],
```

This works for my default route. If you navigate to the base route "localhost:4200/test2" the library's default route correctly loads. However, when a button is clicked and another route is navigated to, the 'test2' base of the library's routes is removed. The page "localhost:4200/page2" loads instead of "localhost:4200/test2/page2". That url doesn't exist and I get an error. However if you navigate to "localhost:4200/test2/page2", the correct page loads.

What is happening to the 'test2' base url on redirect? How do I maintain this base url without changing code in my library?

Comment: can you post your routerConfig for the lazy loaded lib? Also can you post the code or routerLink you're using to navigate to page2?

Comment: can you show the method that handles the button click?

Comment: it is called with this.router.navigate([location]); where location = 'page2/child'

Answer (score 0):

**Update 12/13/19 - use relativeTo**

1) Inject `ActivatedRoute` in your component constructor.

`constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }`

2) `Router.navigate()` accepts a second parameter of type [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#relativeTo). Set the `relativeTo` property using the injected route.

`this.router.navigate(['child'], {relativeTo: this.route});`

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uutxnh?file=src%2Fapp%2Flazy%2Flazy-home%2Flazy-home.component.ts)

Comment: it is called with this.router.navigate([location]); where location = 'page2/child'

Comment: if location is just a String parameter you are passing to a function, make sure that string is something like 'page2' and NOT '/page2'. Having a leading '/' in the front of the string would send you to "localhost:4200/page2"

Comment: There is no leading '/'

Comment: @AaronFriedman the issue may be the `/` in the `location` string.  Try `this.router.navigate(location.split('/'))`

Comment: I tried the split, but no luck. It navigated to page2/child. Not test2/page2/child

Comment: updated answer using NavigationExtras, and included a StackBlitz